# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable when using pd.Series.map

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

For:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': (1,1,2,3,3), 'b':(20,21,30,40,41)})
```

Why is only this working

```
df['b_new'] = df.a.map(df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1))
```

but not:

```
>>df['b_new'] = df.a.map(df.groupby('a').nth(-1))
...
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

although both:

```
>>df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1)

    b
a    
1  21
2  30
3  41
```

and

```
df.groupby('a').nth(-1)

-
    b
a    
1  21
2  30
3  41
```

do deliver quite similar results.

(see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924467/7450524

Comment: Try this: `type(df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1))` and `type(df.groupby('a').nth(-1))`
One is returning a dataframe the other one a series.

Comment: You should know series mapping works only with another series.

Comment: `df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1)`does not return what you say.

Comment: @Dark Indeed, it's even mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to understand why my answer works, then this is why.

Consider -

```
df.groupby('a').nth(-1)

    b
a    
1  21
2  30
3  41
```

`nth` is applied to *each column* of each group, resulting in a dataframe. In your case, there is only one column.

However, in this case -

```
df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1)

a
1    21
2    30
3    41
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

`nth` is applied *only* to `b`, so the result is a series.

Now, take a look at the docs for [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), in particular, what you can pass to it -

> `arg` : function, dict, or Series

A callable, `dict`, or `pd.Series` object. You cannot pass a dataframe! What `map` does, is it uses the index of the series as the indexer into the series you call `map` on, and replaces it the corresponding value for *that* index.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference - if not specify column it return `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.groupby('a').nth(-1))
    b
a    
1  21
2  30
3  41
```

And with specify return `Series`:

```
print (df.groupby('a').b.nth(-1))
a
1    21
2    30
3    41
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Error means `map` working with `Series`, not with `DataFrame`, although it is only one column `df`.